# python json validation using jsonschemas

Tags: json, python-3.x, jsonschema

I have a problem, and ai don't know how start.

I have a json example:

```
{
  "vcn_keys": {
    "name_1": {
      "compartment_id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..jlq",
      "cidr": "11.0.0.0/16",
      "subnets": {
        "sub_poc1_1": {
          "compartment_id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..jlq",
          "name": "sub_vcn1_1",
          "cidr": "10.0.0.0/24"
        }
      }
    },
    "name_2": {
      "compartment_id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..jlq",
      "cidr": "10.0.0.0/16",
      "subnets": {
        "sub_poc2_1": {
          "compartment_id": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..jlq",
          "name": "sub_vcn2_1",
          "cidr": 456
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a jsonschema for this json example:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "User",
  "description": "A user request json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "vcn_keys": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "compartment_id": {
              "description": "ocid info",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "cidr": {
              "description": "cdir range",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "subnets": {
              "type": "object",
              "patternProperties": {
                "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "compartment_id": {
                      "description": "ocid info",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "name": {
                      "description": "ocid info",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "cidr": {
                      "description": "cdir range",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I test it on this page : https://jsonschema.dev/s/LMl3N

And it's working, for example if a change a value inside subnet object to number instead string ... it WORKS

How i can so the same with PYTHON?

***update***

this is my first draft, but it doesn't work, don't show me the error:

```
import json
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import validate

def get_schema():
    with open('schema_v6.json', 'r') as file:
        schema = json.load(file)
    return schema

def validate_json(json_data):
    execute_api_schema = get_schema()
    try:
        validate(instance=json_data, schema=execute_api_schema)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as err:
        print(err)
        err = "Given JSON data is InValid"
        return False, err

    message = "Given JSON data is Valid"
    return True, message

f = open('sample_v7.json')

data = json.load(f)

for i, obj in enumerate(data['vcn_keys']):
    try:
        # validate(instance=obj, schema=schema)
        print(data)
        validate_json(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"obj {i} invalid: {e}")
    else:
        print(f"obj {i} valid")

for obj in data['vcn_keys']:
    print(data)
```

Regards

Comment: Did you already take a look at the available implementations for Python here? https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators

Comment: yes, let me update my question , with the python script part

Comment: I am not familiar with Python but just to make sure, you are not passing the single vcn_keys as objects to the validator? Because your schema does expect a top-level vcn_keys property and in this case, this property would not be present and no validation takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Clemens is correct that you are not passing the full data object to the validator, but rather the contents of the `vcn_keys` property.

You can see this generate an error by adding `"required": ["vcn_keys"]` to the top of your schema.